# $2^{10 - x} \cdot 2^{10 - x} = 4^{10-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

$$2^{10 - x} \cdot 2^{10 - x} = 4^{10-x}$$
Is that correct?

I would've done

$$
2^{10 - x} \cdot 2^{10 - x}\;\; = \;\;
(2)^{10 - x + 10 - x} \; = \; (2)^{2 \cdot (10 - x)} \;=\; 4^{10 - x}\tag{1}
$$

Is that allowed?

---

If so, can I say that

$$
\frac{4^x}{2^y} =  2^{x - y} \tag{2}
$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\text{Yes:}\;\;\;\large 2^{10 - x} \cdot 2^{10 - x} =\; 4^{10-x}\tag{1.a}$$

> $$\underbrace{\large 2^{10 - x} \cdot 2^{10 - x} 
> = (2)^{10 - x + 10 - x} = (2)^{2 \cdot (10 - x)} = 4^{10 - x}}\tag{1.b}
> $$
>   $$\text{Yes, that is that is allowed.}$$

> $$\underbrace{
> \large \frac{4^x}{2^y} =  2^{x - y}}\;\;\; ?\tag{2 ?}$$
>   $$\text{NOT correct. See below:}$$

$$(2)\quad \large \frac{4^x}{2^y} \;=\; 4^x \cdot 2^{-y} \;= \;(2^2)^x \cdot 2^{-y} \;=\; 2^{(2x)} \cdot 2^{(-y)} \;=\;2^{(2x-y)}$$

Comment: @Kaish: Does this answer your question? Is it all clear now?

Answer (score 4):

First statement is correct, but $4^x/2^y = 2^{2x-y}$.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that correct?

Yes!

Notice how you converted $2^2$ to $4$ in your first statement. You can do the *vice-versa* as well. Let's make a little alteration:$${4^x \over 2^y} \Leftrightarrow {2^{{\color{#00}{2x}}} \over 2^y} \Leftrightarrow {2^{2x - y}}$$That's it!